# how to get a list of meta data fields assocaited with a custom post type

Tags: post-meta

I am using a theme which has defined a custom post type--

Now, I am trying to retrieve the list of metadata fields used by that post type-- so that I can insert data via PHP code in form of that custom post--I just want the list of meta data fields(not the values of metadata fields for specific posts-- but the list of metadata fields for that type of custom post).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about post meta-- data stored in the `$wpdb->postmeta` table when you talk about "meta data fields". [The data in that table is associated with particular posts, of whatever type. It is not in any way keyed directly to the post type itself.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta) There would be no way to connect a meta data field with a post type except by `JOIN`ing on the `$wpdb->posts` table based on the post ID and checking the `post_type` for that post ID.

You can't have meta data associated with a post type without having posts in that post type.

The only way I could see around that is if your theme has hard-coded post type meta data or stores that date somewhere else-- the `$wpdb->options` table perhaps-- or if maybe the meta data keys are in some way identifiable by name-- say `books_cpt_author` for a `books` post type. If that is the case, how you would get that information depends on how the theme has created/stored the data, and your question doesn't contain enough information to guess at that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_post_custom_keys()`:

```
$fields = get_post_custom_keys( get_the_ID() );
```

Comment: will this work even when no post has yet been made on the custom post type-- this is a new template i have just purchased... thanks

Comment: No, this works only for a given post ID.